# Как узнать количество символов в строке на C#?

Tags: c#, строки

Как в коде можно реализовать подсчет количества символов в строке? Я смотрел на MSDN -> класс `String`, вроде бы не нашел ничего похожего.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Наверное у вас другая MSDN....

[String.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/system.string.length.aspx)

Comment: Извините, значит я затупил:)